# How can you display a Unicode character on Android that otherwise appears as ☒?

Tags: fonts, special-chars

I want to display the character ⮚ on my phone. However, whenever I open any app containing this character, it is displayed as ☒. I am aware that this is due to the font limitations of Android. Is there any way to resolve this?

Comment: What device and are you rooted? Have you seen this: https://medium.com/@droidbyme/special-character-in-android-c7f10a490911

Comment: I am on Samsung Galaxy A5 2017 without root. Isn't that link just for app developers?

Comment: Let experiment a bit. Try this [keyboard](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.husseinelfeky.characterpad&hl=en). Search for "white space" when you open it. Copy the character and paste in a another app. Is it displayed corectly or not?

Comment: Have you try those: &#x27A2; or &#10146;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of now there is no way to install fonts globally for all applications. I would advice you to write to app developer.

Also this character should be displayed correctly in your web browser.

In conclusion best way is to approach your application developer by following a feedback channel or writing a review if no feedback or support channel is provided.

Apps like 
[WPS Office](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=cn.wps.moffice_eng&referrer=utm_source=wpsweb) support this

Comment: I encounter the same problem. Just open this Question url in Chrome browser in Android... this sign ⮚ will not be displayed... :(